# Unity How to check if a child object has a certain script or is a certain type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a tower defense game. I have towers as child objects of tiles. I need to check if a certain tower is on a certain tile. What I'm currently doing is this:

```
Tiles[new Point(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y)].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Tower>() is IfStat)
```

IfStat is a class derived from tower. But this returns false. How can I check is the tower -child- has IfStat on it as the script?

Thanks.

Comment: just a comment since I'm not sure - can you do `...GetComponent<Tower>().GetChild(0)` ? If `IfStat` is a child of the `Tower` component, then checking `Tower` won't get you anywhere.

Comment: also, is your `Tower` component actually a child of `tile.transform`?

Comment: Tower is not used anywhere, instead the derived classes are attached to game objects I use as towers (like IfStat is attached to a certain game object which is used as a tower). And the game objects I use as towers are child objects of tiles.

Comment: is there only one child on the Tile?

Comment: yes only 1 child on each tile

Comment: and you are sure that the tile at the X and Y you send in actually has a Tower component?

Comment: `SCRIPT_NAME script = gameObject.getComponentInChildren<SCRIPT_NAME >()` where gameObject is the Tile, and the tower is the child of the tile. This would belong in a script attached to the Tile

Comment: yes I'm sure because I use X, Y coordinates for path finding so they're not wrong and the very same tile has a tower on it I can see it in the inspector.

Comment: and how should I use it in the if statement?@TehTris

Comment: just check if its null, or use the plural form getComponentsInChildren and check it against the length.

Comment: Thanks It worked. @TehTris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

Tile is a GameObject with tile_script.cs attached to it.

Tower is a GameObject with tower_script.cs attached to it, and is a Child of TILE ( ie in hierarchy, its underneath the > icon of it )

Inside tile_script.cs you would get the tower_script by doing

```
tower_script script = gameObject.getComponentInChildren<tower_script>()
```

If you want to verify its existence, check it against null like `if (script != null)` ... which simplifies to `if (script)` or change to the plural version `getComponentsInChildren` and check `if (script.Length >= 1)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do the job?

```
var ifstat = Tiles[new Point(currentPos.X, currentPos.Y)].transform.GetComponentInChildren<IfStat>();
if (ifstat != null)
{
    //Do whatever you wish with ifstat
}
```